# .entry-content ul li chops off words randomly (phone only)

Tags: css

I am not very good at CSS and I know just enough to customize my [site.](https://9tailedkitsune.com/)

The problem I am facing is related to `.entry-content ul li` elements. On pc, they are shown normally, words don't break randomly but on phone, they break randomly at any character - for example, supernatural will be "supernatura" and the next line under will contain the remaining "l".

I am desperate and don't know how to fix it.
I tried the code they recommended

```
.entry-content ul li{
   word-break: break-all;
   max-width: 420px;
}
```

but that messed up my pc version, which was doing the same (breaking words randomly at any random letter) and did not fix my phone version either so I had to remove it completely.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There use to be a word-break value of 'break-word' but that ended up getting deprecated.  Rather than using word-break, try replacing it with 'overflow-wrap: break-word' and that should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried to insert this CSS:

`.entry-content ul li 
{ overflow-wrap: break-word;
}`

But it had no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who recommended you that kind of code, because that code will literally break it and will not compatible in all devices, it looks to me that you're having trouble in the genre tags overlapping of text. You might try this one below, I'll keep changing my answer until we got it correctly:

```
.entry-content ul li{
   white-space: nowrap;
   max-width: unset;
   overflow: unset;
   width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code seems to be causing everything to overflow when checking on my phone. 

The one who recommended it was the theme's support.